# Problem converting PDF to ZPL for print with Zebra printer

Tags: python, pdf, converters, zpl

Are there solution for this problem? I have a PDF file, I have to convert it to a ZPL file for sending to a Zebra printer. I have searched online for solutions, but none work.

I tried module zplgrf, PIL, and open PDF with function 'open(pdf, "rb")' and send to Zebra. I use socket module for sending to printer.

Comment: I don't use python but can give you the gist of what needs to be done.  You need to convert each page of the PDF to a monochrome (1-bit black/white) PNG image.  And then send each image as a separate label format.  If you can convert the PDF to PNGs, I can help you with the ZPL.

Comment: @MarkWarren I was able to convert file pdf in png, when i finally send zpl to zebra, print the label which then goes back, before the cutter. Solution please?

Comment: Can you please explain the problem more?  Also, read over the `^MM` Print Mode command to ensure you have the printer configured to use the cutter.

Comment: @MarkWarren this was exactly the problem, and I solved it by editing the ^ MM command